# Simple Text-based game using classes. Trying to create a basic loop for if has a particular item in the inventory. Then open the door

Tags: python, game-engine

My problem actually occurs in LockedRoom():

The error python throws is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tank\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Enthought\CastleGame1.py", line 479, in <module>
    a_game.play()
  File "C:\Users\Tank\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Enthought\CastleGame1.py", line 33, in play
    next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
  File "C:\Users\Tank\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Enthought\CastleGame1.py", line 147, in enter
    has_key = "key" in Person.items
AttributeError: class Person has no attribute 'items'
```

So, I believe the problem is to do with checking for, or putting "Key" in the
person's items. I then want to check this list to see if the warrior is carrying it. If he is, then he should be able to open the door. If not, then the door should remain closed. I need to repeat this again at the end for TowerRoom. In that case, I need to check for up to 3 different items. I have attached the code. Hopefully, the error is a very simple one.

```
from sys import exit 
from random import randint

key = False
brick = False
candle = False
Cup = False

class Scene(object):

    def enter(self):
        print "This scene is not yet configured."
        exit(1)

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.items = []

class Engine(object):

    def __init__(self, scene_map):
        self.scene_map = scene_map

    def play(self):
        current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()
        last_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene('finished')

        while current_scene != last_scene:
            next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
            current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)

        current_scene.enter()

class Death(Scene):
    quips =[
        "You really suck at this.",
        "Why don't you try a little harder next time.",
        "Well... that was a very stupid thing to do.",
        "I have a small puppy that's better at this than you.",
        "why don't you just give up now.",
        "Please, stop killing me!",
        "Your mom would be proud of you... if she were smarter."
    ]

    def enter(self):
        print Death.quips[randint(0, len(self.quips)-1)]
        exit(0)

class MainGate(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print "Welcome to Luke's first Text based game."
        print "It currently has no name, nor will it ever have one."
        print "Because it kind of sucks a little bit."
        print"----------------------------------------"
        print "Evil Dr. Onion has stollen the Mushroom Kingdoms princess"
        print "You have chased him down for months through rain, snow"
        print "and desserts. You have finally tracked him down."
        print "In front of you is a huge castle. You go through the giant"
        print "entrance to begin your search for the princess. Nobody"
        print "know what may await you ahead."
        print "Do you want to enter the Castle?"
        print "1. Yes"
        print "2. No"

        action = raw_input(">")
        if action == '1':
           return 'central_corridor'

        elif action == '2':
            print "What? You are leaving and giving up on the princess"
            print "already? God will certainly smite you for this!!!"
            return 'death'

        else:
            print "Please choose an action numerically using the numpad"
            print "on your computer."
            return 'MainGate'

class CentralCorridor(Scene):
    def enter(self):
        print "You enter the castle. In fron of you stands a giant onion"
        print "monster. It looks at you with its big, bulging eye. Your"
        print "own eyes begin to weep as you look at this... thing."
        print "The giant onion monster begins to charge at you, waving its"
        print "sword over what I suppose would be its head."
        print "what do you do?"
        print "1. Try and fight the giant onion with your sword."
        print "2. Try and dodge out of the way of the onion and run past it."
        print "3. Throw something at the onion."
        print "4. Stand there and scream at the onion."

        action = raw_input(">")
        if action == '1':
            print "You take your sword out of its sheath. Waiting for the onion"
            print "to reach you so that you can stab it in its giant eye."
            print "however as it gets closer its stench gets worse and worse."
            print "It gets so bad that you can hardly see!"
            print "You try and swing at the onion, and miss!"
            print "You feel a stabbing pain in your right shoulder"
            print "and then everything goes black."
            return 'death'

        elif action == '2':
            print "As the onion charges you, you jump out of the way."
            print "However, the giant onion is much quicker than you expected."
            print "You look down to see a sword protruding from your stomach."
            print "You scream in pain and die."
            return 'death'

        elif action == '3':
            print "You look in your pockets to find something to throw at"
            print "the onion."

            print "You find a rubber duck and throw it at the onion. Unfortunately, it" 
            print "does nothing but distracts the onion from you for a few"
            print "short seconds. After it focuses its attention back on you,"
            print "it eats your face off."
            return 'death'

        elif action == '4':
            print "You choose to stand and scream at the onion at the highest"
            print "pitch your girly little voice will allow."
            print "The onion, hearing your scream, is terrified. It turns"
            print "around and rolls away as quickly as its little legs and can"
            print "carry it. You quickly catch up with it and cut its little"
            print "legs right off, before hurrying to the next room."
            return 'locked_room'

        else:
            print "please choose an appropriate action dear sir. Otherwise,"
            print "you will never be able to rescue the princess."
            return 'central_corridor'


class LockedRoom(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print "You are standing in a room with just a door in front of you."
        print "What do you do?"
        print "1. Try and open the door."

        has_key = "key" in Person.items
        if not has_key: print "2. pick up the key"

        action = raw_input(">")

        if (action == '1' and has_key):
            print "You unlock and open the door."
            return 'monty_hall_room'

        elif (action == '1' and not has_key):
            print "the door will not budge"
            return 'locked_room'

        elif (action == '2' and not has_key):
            print "you picked up the key."
            Person.items.append("key")
            return 'locked_room'

        else:
            print "Please enter a numeric value as something to do."
            print "Otherwise we might be here all day."
            return 'locked_room'





class Finished(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print "You won! Good job."
        return 'finished'

class Map(object):

    scenes = {
        'main_gate': MainGate(),
        'central_corridor': CentralCorridor(),
        'locked_room': LockedRoom(),
        'monty_hall_room': MontyHallRoom(),
        'pickel_room': PickleRoom(),
        'death': Death(),
        'finished': Finished(),
   }

    def __init__(self, start_scene):
        self.start_scene = start_scene

    def next_scene(self, scene_name):
        val = Map.scenes.get(scene_name)
        return val

    def opening_scene(self):
        return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)


warrior = Person("Soldat")
a_map = Map('central_corridor')
a_game = Engine(a_map)
a_game.play()
```

I just need a way to use a class 'list' and put things in and out of it in the other classes. Then, use whatever is contained in that list to open a door or slay a monster.

Any help anyone could provide would be greatly appreciatd.

Comment: The problem is that you are calling class definiton `Person` instead of instance of the class, what you actualyl want to call is `warrior`.

Answer (score -2):

You need create a "person" instance (you already did this), instead of using the class:

```
warrior = Person.new("penne12")
```

Or use the one you created

Then you can use your "warrior":

```
warrior.name #=> "penne12"
warrior.items #=> []
```

This is because the class itself doesn't store the name or items, the instance of the class (created when you do `Person.new`) contains the item array and the name. Trying to get the attributes of the class won't work.

[Further reading](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_class_and_instance_attributes.php)

Comment: Not exactly answer to the question, as he already created the warrior instance and the tabs are just formatting issue when copy pasting. And It help to wait more than 2 seconds for someone to be able to write explanation for downvote ;)

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul Ah! I see, didn't see he defined the warrior class. Also, the tabs aren't a copy paste issue (explain why other tabs are there). I fixed it to use the warrier var he already defined. Could you please remove the downvote?

Comment: You would have a different error if it was tabs issue as the code as it is will not run. And that still doesn't technically answer the question of OP, but if he can extrapolate from it he is free to upvote.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul It does solve the problem - the error message is `class Person has no attribute 'items'`, because he is calling the class (not an instance of the class). My answer solves his problem. Can you please remove the down vote, as it is not constructive.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul I still don't understand what's wrong with my answer - it solves the question, and explains how. Could you explain how it's wrong or remove the down vote? Please?

Comment: @penne12 If it was an indentation error, the message given would be either `IndentationError: expected an indented block` or `SyntaxError: expected an indented block` depending on which version of Python he was running. It certainly wouldn't be an `AttributeError`.

Comment: @KalZekdor removed the first part of my answer, is it good now?

Comment: @KalZekdor Awesome! Thanks!